# How to set an object creation count to exactly 15 for a class in Java

Tags: object

This was asked to me in an interview and puzzled me. Please let me know if this can be done programatically and also in the Server.

Comment: Very unclear what you mean. Do you want to write a class that can only be instantiated 15 times? And what is "the server" ?

Comment: That sounds like it requires context you haven't provided. That, or it just makes no sense. The answer could be anything from "assignment operator" to "make 15 objects" to "check the current value and make 15-current value objects" to "there is no such count" to plenty of other options.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the owner of the class, you should declare a class variable and increase the count in Class constructor every time constructor is invoked and raise some error on 15th count.